# Scroll Directive Not Working in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Sorry for the dumb question. I am new to angular JS. I found a nice small scroll directive from http://jsfiddle.net/88TzF/622/ But it is not working when i create the below HTML
    
              Dropdown Example

```
      <ul class="dropdown-menu Container" scroll>
              <div >
          <li ng-repeat="i in items"><a href="#">{{i.value}}</a></li>
                  </div>
        </ul>


      </div>
```

But if i do the jQuery Way scroll event if firing. Can you please let me know what's going wrong.

Items array has 700+ objects. So it is overflowing.

```
    .Container
{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That directive binds to the window scroll; it won't fire if an overflowing div scrolls.

Comment: If I understand correctly you wish to log message wether or not header is visible by hard coding it's height? But are you sure you are listening to correct event? If you wish to listen event on some container div, you should bind event to that element. So instead of window use element, provided by directive to bind events on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/88TzF/625/ Something like that? Binding events to directive element should do.

Comment: Hi Clem, 
I am actually trying to get the scroll offset.

Comment: Perfect exactly what i was looking for Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding scroll event to window, but I assume you are scrolling dropdown container?

If that's the case then you will have to bind scroll event to dropdown container, and checking for `this.scrollTop` in your if statement.

However, don't forget to unbind scroll event as angular will not be able to handle this on his own.

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on("scroll", function() {
               if (this.scrollTop >= 100) {
                   scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                   console.log('Scrolled below header.');
               } else {
                   scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                   console.log('Header is in view.');
               }
              scope.$apply(); // Prefer scope.$digest()!
          });
        
        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
          element.off('scroll');
        });
      };
  });
```

```css
.dropdown-container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="test">
  <div class="dropdown-container" scroll>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```